# Проблема авторизации vk api

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

После успешного ввода логина и пароля, получаю данную ошибку:

```
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err: java.lang.InterruptedException
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKSyncRequestUtil.executeSyncWithListener(VKSyncRequestUtil.java:77)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.executeSyncWithListener(VKRequest.java:242)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.krava.vkmessenger.data.repository.datasource.CloudDataSource$5.call(CloudDataSource.java:151)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.krava.vkmessenger.data.repository.datasource.CloudDataSource$5.call(CloudDataSource.java:143)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10140)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10140)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:228)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
04-10 19:42:52.762 2051-2143/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err: java.lang.Exception
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.krava.vkmessenger.data.repository.datasource.CloudDataSource$5$1.onError(CloudDataSource.java:165)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKSyncRequestUtil$Listener.onError(VKSyncRequestUtil.java:60)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.provideError(VKRequest.java:434)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.access$100(VKRequest.java:56)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest$1.onComplete(VKRequest.java:344)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest$1.onComplete(VKRequest.java:332)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpOperation$1.onComplete(VKHttpOperation.java:187)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKAbstractOperation$1.run(VKAbstractOperation.java:87)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
04-10 19:42:52.781 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
04-10 19:42:56.917 2051-2138/com.krava.vkmessenger V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
04-10 19:42:56.935 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action: com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
04-10 19:42:56.937 2051-2051/com.krava.vkmessenger V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
```

Исходный код проекта - https://github.com/krava2008/Messenger-for-VK 
Прошу помощи, уже мозг кипит.

Comment: Вы б хоть код показали... А то не всем охота на гитХаб лезль и там самостоятельно рыскать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте залогиниться и попользоваться api вручную, с помощью [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), используя те же параметры, что и в коде.